# Kendo Tree view - How to load child node without expand

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I want to check all child nodes when the parent node is checked without expand.

Can anyone help to me? 
sorry for my english

```
        $("#organtreeview").kendoTreeView({
        checkboxes: true,
        width:200,
        dataSource: orgListData,
        loadOnDemand:true,
        dataTextField:"shortName",
        checkboxes: {
                checkChildren: true
        },
        check:function(){
            var treeview=$("#organtreeview").data("kendoTreeView");
            var nodes = treeview.dataSource.view();
        },
        // expand on selection
        select: function(e) {

        }
    });
```

in the check event,I want to get all checked nodes without expand current node.
if the child nodes of the checked node will not be expand,so the child nodes cannot be checked.

Comment: elaborate. show some code, so that people will know what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `loadOnDemand:true` and `checkChildren:true` are set, the child nodes will be checked automatically, as soon as they load. From this point of view, the TreeView will work as expected.

However, if you want to obtain the checked **child** nodes **immediately** in the `check` event, you will need to expand the parent node, so that the children are loaded. Here is an example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/IYeMi

The alternative option is to use `loadOnDemand:false`, then you will not need any of the described custom logic.